# How to convert Satoshi to bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-cash

hi people just i am join on this site.can anyone Help by telling me how to convert Satoshi into bitcoin?

Answer (score 5):

Satoshi is simply a denomination, not a different currency.

1 BTC is comprised of 100000000 Satoshi, similarly to how 1 dollar is 100 cents.

To convert between them, all you need to do is multiply or divide by 10^8.

For example, `1 BTC` is `10^8  * 1 Satoshi`. Similarly, `10000 Satoshi` is equivalent to `10000/10^8`, or `0.0001 BTC`.

Answer (score 0):

[1 bitcoin = 100 million satoshis](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_(unit))